# Passing enum value in restfull api

Tags: api, rest, enums

I have this scenario at hand:

1. I have an API server holding enum value and sending it using Restfull API.
2. The client will receive it and needs to act according to the value.

My main question: Which is better - sending the int value or the string?  I can see benefits for both approaches.

Is there any way to avoid holding the enum in both sides? I am not familiar with one that actually can be useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the API server maintains the enum, the client could fetch it by:

```
GET /enums
```

... which will return a list of enum values:

```
[
  { "id" : "1001", "value" : "enum-item-1" },
  { "id" : "1002", "value" : "enum-item-2" },
  ...
  { "id" : "100N", "value" : "enum-item-3" },
]
```

Thus allowing the client to fetch one of the enum items:

```
GET /enums/1017
```

Or perhaps perform an operation on it:

```
POST /enums/1017/disable
```

Normally, one would only refer to the enum items by their unique ID - and if the client always starts by querying the server for the enum list, you will not need to maintain the enum on the client and server.

But - if the values in your business case are permanently unique and there is a compelling reason to have 'nicer' human-readable URLs, one could use:

```
GET /enums/enum-item-26
```

Generally, this is not best practice, as the enum item value probably has business meaning and thus might change. Even though that currently seems unlikely.

Comment: Thanks but this case seems a little odd since apart from getting the enum value the client has to actually do something with the value and fetching the enum wont effect it's logic, just the translation.

Comment: What do you mean 'do something with the value'? Will the client fetch the enum values and then modify some of them?

Comment: I mean that when the client gets the new enum,  and it contains new values,  since the client code didn't change,  no flow will use the new enum values.

Comment: OK - I think I understand now. Is it possible that the enum could contain the all details of the flow? The client would then simply fetch the enum and do as it says.